# MySQL How LIKE 1 digit

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this records:

```
Number
1, 2
1, 24
```

How to select only 2 by LIKE not 2 and 24

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE number LIKE '%2%'
```

> 1, 2  // need only this record

> 1, 24

Comment: How should that first row with four numbers be split into two rows?

Comment: So... just to make sure... your `Number` column is not a number, but a string that contains two numbers separated by a comma? And you wish to match the second of those numbers? Or any of tthem?

Comment: You must not store multiple information (two numbers in your case) in a single column. This violates database normalization (1st normal form) and is not how a relational datbase should be designed. Fix your data model and you dn't have to use (slow) tricks to access your data.

Answer (score 1):

[`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) **almost** does what you want, but you'll have to remove the spaces in order to use it:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   test
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('2', REPLACE(number, ' ', '')) > 0
```

Comment: No need for `>0`, https://dbfiddle.uk/LN9KASVX

Comment: This answer [does not work](https://dbfiddle.uk/y1rDdKxN) for the OP's data given as stated, because the CSV elements are also space separated.

Comment: @Ergest Basha: When saying so, you should also explain why this is the case. In MySQL 0 is treated as false, values <> 0 as true. `FIND_IN_SET` returns 0 when not found, > 0 when found, and NULL when number is null. As we are looking for > 0, we can omit this accordingly. And yes, Tim is right, we would have to remove blanks first anyway to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoiding storing unnormalized CSV data like this.  That being said, if you must proceed, here is one way:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM test
WHERE CONCAT(' ', number, ' ') LIKE '% 2 %';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows :

```
SELECT `number`
FROM `test` 
WHERE TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`number`, ',', -1)) = 2 or TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`number`, ',', 1)) = 2;
```

`SUBSTRING_INDEX` to split number, and `TRIM` to remove any space, then we search in to parts of the number.